# How to setText after database call

Tags: android, firebase, textview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. I have a TextView (contained in a fragment) which needs to hold data coming from firebase (coming from a listener contained in MainActivity). I haven't been programming java long, so I'm wondering what my options are aside from making the textview static (as this is bad practice)?

The below is what is called in MainActivity's onCreate;

```
    private void getExtras(String uid) {
    mFirebaseRef.child("users").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                System.out.println(TAG + "TEST: " + user.getUsername());
                CURRENT_USER.setSex(user.getSex());
                CURRENT_USER.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                CURRENT_USER.setAge(user.getAge());
                CURRENT_USER.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                CURRENT_USER.setCreatedTime(user.getCreatedTime());
                Log.e(TAG, "Logged user is "+ CURRENT_USER.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The below is my fragment's onViewCreated:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tvUserTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvUserTitle);
    tvUserTitle.setText(MainScreen.CURRENT_USER.getUsername());
}
```

As you can see, the fragment is created before the variable is set, thus it shows up blank (null).

Comment: Share some code...

Comment: getting username from MainActivity is not good idea. Why shouldn't call firebase in your fragment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to get your hands on a reference to the Fragment from your MainActivity and then call a method that would set the TextView text.

Inside your `MainActivity` callback

```
CustomFragment customFragment =(CustomFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.custom_frag_id);
customFragment.setTextView(firebaseText);
```

And in your `CustomFragment` class

```
public void setTextView(String text){
    myTextView.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
After receiving the callback that the data has been inserted, get your current fragment from the fragment manager and call a method in the fragment where you can access the UI and change the UI.

YourFragment fragment =(YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
fragment.setTextView(text);

I usually like sending the whole object to the class so that we can use whatever we want whenever we need.

public void updateData(DataModel data) {
this.data = data;
refreshUI(); // reload the content.`enter code here`
}
```